# Using Ajax to generate an alert box after checking whether some data are stored in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Ajax to generate an alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234354/using-ajax-to-generate-an-alert-box)

Hi I want to pop up an alert box after checking whether some data is stored in the database. If stored, it will alert **saved**, else **not saved**.

This is my ajaxfunction

```
AjaxRequest.POST({
  'url': 'GroupsHandler.php',
  'onSuccess': function (creategroupajax) {
    alert('Saved!');
  },
  'onError': function (creategroupajax) {
    alert('not saved');
  }
});
```